# React Native: TextInput disappears when put into View

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, reactjs

Currently I'm learning React Native with the help of a book in which is explained how to build a to do app. However I can't continue because of this error/bug. This is happening in IOS, not sure if this also happens on Android as I haven't set up my Android emulator just jet.

My `<View>` container has two `<TextInputs>`, working fine.
When I wrap both inputs into views, they simply 'disappear'.

Here is my component NoteScreen.js:

```
import React, {
    Component,
    StyleSheet,
    TextInput,
    View
} from 'react-native';

export default class NoteScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                    <TextInput 
                        ref="title" 
                        autoFocus={true} 
                               autoCapitalize="sentences"
            placeholder="Untitled"
            style={styles.title}

            onEndEditing={(text) => {this.refs.body.focus()}}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            ref="body"
            multiline={true}
            placeholder="Start typing"
            style={styles.body}

            textAlignVertical="top"
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          />
        </View>
        </View>
        );
    }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 64
    },
    textInput: {
        color: '#ffffff',
        flex: 1,
        width: 60,
        height: 60,
        fontSize: 16
    },
    inputContainer: {
        borderBottomColor: '#9E7CE3',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginBottom: 10
    },
    title: {
        fontFamily: 'Overpass-Bold',
        height: 40
    },
    body: {
        fontFamily: 'Overpass-Bold',
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

I did some research and noticed some weird things;

- Both of my inputs have a width and a height
- The inputs vanish also if they don't have any styles applied to them
- This only happens with text inputs, normal text just renders.

Some insight would be great, I'm thinking this is a bug, or I am just overlooking something..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried your example (on android), and with exact code you provided, screen is completely empty. Without styles on text input, they are not showing, and you've set styles.title and styles.body to your TextInput components -> in styles.title and styles.body you don't have (both) width and height. So what you can do is:

- Add `width` to your title and body styles

or

- Add styles to text input in array and apply both styles for textInput and for title/body like this: `style={[styles.textInput, styles.title]}` and `style={[styles.textInput, styles.body]}`

Here is working code for both suggestions i gave you:

```
import React, {
AppRegistry,
    Component,
    StyleSheet,
    TextInput,
    View
} from 'react-native';

export default class NoteScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                        ref="title"
                        autoFocus={true}
                        autoCapitalize="sentences"
                        placeholder="Untitled"
                        style={styles.title}

                        onEndEditing={(text) => {this.refs.body.focus()}}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                        ref="body"
                        multiline={true}
                        placeholder="Start typing"
                        style={[styles.textInput, styles.body]}

                        textAlignVertical="top"
                        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 64
    },
    textInput: {
        color: '#ffffff',
        flex: 1,
        width: 60,
        height: 60,
        fontSize: 16
    },
    inputContainer: {
        borderBottomColor: '#9E7CE3',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginBottom: 10
    },
    title: {
        fontFamily: 'Overpass-Bold',
        height: 40,
        width: 40
    },
    body: {
        fontFamily: 'Overpass-Bold',
        flex: 1
    }

});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your answer! Apperently I did post my old code, I had both styles.textInput AND styles.body / title applied, however, I didn't put them in an array.

Answer (score 2):

I believe we are reading the same book, becausee I had the same problem.

I solved it by removing the `alignItems: 'center'` in the *container* style and adding `flex: 1` to the *inputContainer* style. It still doesn't look like the book sample, but at least the fields are now visible.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
import React, { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from "react-native";
import dismissKeyboard from "dismissKeyboard";

export default class NoteScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {
        handleTitleEditingEnd = (text) => { this.refs.body.focus(); };

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                        ref="title"
                        placeholder="Untitled"
                        style={[styles.textInput, styles.title]}
                        onEndEditing={handleTitleEditingEnd}
                        returnKeyType="next"
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                        ref="body"
                        multiline={true}
                        placeholder="Start typing"
                        style={[styles.textInput, styles.body]}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        // alignItems: "center",
        marginTop: 64
    },
    inputContainer: {
        borderBottomColor: "#9E7CE3",
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
        marginBottom: 10,
        flex: 1,
    },
    textInput: {
        flex: 1,
        fontSize: 16,
    }, 
    title: {
        height: 40,
    },
    body: {
        flex: 1,
    }
});
```

Comment: how does adding flex:1 fixes this ?

Comment: Can't recall, it's been almost 6 years since I answered this. However, it did fix it ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

If your `<Text>` don't have height in your `<View>`, try removing `flex : 1` from your container.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with code below:

```
import React, {
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class NoteScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput ref="title" autoFocus={true} autoCapitalize="sentences" placeholder="Untitled" style={[styles.textInput, styles.title]} onEndEditing={(text) => {this.refs.body.focus()} }/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput ref="body" multiline={true} placeholder="Start typing" style={[styles.textInput, styles.body]}/>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 64
  },
  title: {
    height: 40
  },
  body: {
    height: 160,
    flex: 1
  },
  inputContainer: {
    borderBottomColor: '#9E7CE3',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginBottom: 10
  },
  textInput: {
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 16,
    width: 300,
  }
});
```